# How do I create a RAID 0 volume on Dell Optiplex ICH7R?

Tags: windows-7, sata, storage, raid-0, intel-core2

I just bought a second-hand **Dell Optiplex 330**, Core2Duo 2.2GHz with G31 & ICH7R, which has a fresh installed Windows 7 Home Premium. The specifications sheet from Intel said ICH7R supports both RAID 0 & RAID 1.

In the BIOS, the **SATA mode is set to RAID**, at the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> menu after the POST screen  only allows me to create RAID 1 volume. I've plugged in 3 combination of HDD, 80GB, 320GB and 640GB.

After installing windows on the 80GB, I tried to use both the Intel Matrix Storage Console and the later version of Intel Rapid Storage technology, neither would allow me to create a RAID 0 volume. The combo-box only shows RAID 1.

Updating the latest driver and latest BIOS also doesn't help.

Comment: I don't think you'll want to use that combination, you will get 240 GB striped as a result. Read about [RAID 0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_0). I don't directly see why it's not supported though...

Comment: I'm not really going for that combo, I just happen to have those, so I test and see if whichever one allows me to do RAID 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer in the Dell's User Guide pg 95

> Of the RAID 
>   configurations available in the computer industry for different uses, Dell 
>   offers RAID level 1 on your computer

Now I wonder if there's a way to by pass?

Comment: No, it is a bios limitation set by Dell, you would have to hack the dell bios to contain the full Intel Raid Option ROM firmware.